# I'm really confused about categorizing my models within models in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I haven't written any code yet about this so I think I'll explain this  idea to the best of my abilities,so I'm making a payments backend for a personal project using Django rest framework and the problem is within the  models of my transactions app, now when making a payment I want the models to be categorized into two models,deposits and transfers and those two further sub-categorized into their types  e.g wallet to bank transfer or bank deposit but I have no idea how to sub-categorize the models further please help me

I tried creating a base model but I got stuck and confused

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do something this, here is one example:

**models.py**

```py
class Wallet(models.Models):
    nickname = models.CharField(...)  # nickname of wallet
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='wallets')  # FK to user, a user can have many wallets  

class Transfer(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(...)  # amount in dollars of transfer
    transfer_type = models.CharField(choices=TransferType.choice, ...)  # the type of transfer, (i.e. credit, debit), inherits choices from the TransferType class
    wallet = models.ForeignKey('Wallet', related_name='transfers', ...)  # FK to a wallet, a wallet can have many transfers
    user = models.ForeignKey('Wallet', related_name='transfers', ...)  # FK to a user, a user can have many transfers
```

## EDIT

Some use case examples to illustrate how the relations work:

```py
# given a wallet, get the user's email:
user_email = wallet.user.email

# get the queryset of all wallets for a user:
user_wallets_qs = user.wallets.all()

# get all transfers for a user from the wallet nicknamed "piggy_bank"
transfers = user.transfers.filter(wallet__nickname="piggy_bank")
```

Comment: Please if you could expand your code I'd really appreciate it

Comment: I gave some basic examples, but let me know if you have specific questions